# How to use a code within a .jar file while writing a program in NetBeans

Tags: java, import, jar, mp3, id3

I am trying to use the [jAudioPackage](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_id3.jsp) in a class project. I need it's functionality of getting the id3 tag info from the header of a MP3 file. I looked at the website and once you have everything set-up it seems pretty easy to use. I am just having trouble with actually importing the .jar file which contains the code. How would I go about this in NetBeans?

To summarize, I have the .jar file I just dont know how to get to use the code within the file.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and go to `Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder` and select the jar file in the following dialog. It should then have access to it when coding/compiling.

Comment: I did that...but now how would I go about actually using the code inside it. Do I have the import it still?

Comment: Yep that's right, you'd just declare an `import` statement at the top of your class file. Adding the jar file is just telling Netbeans/javac where to find your imports, but it's all driven from import statements.

Comment: [screenshot of what it looks like](http://imgur.com/a/kIZ7U)

i did what you said about adding it to the library but how do i actually import it. I tried putting "import jaudiotagger-2.0.3;" but that didnt work

[I want to hopefully later get to use the methods listed here](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_read.jsp)

Comment: The `import` keyword in Java specifies the path to a class file to import. What jar file the class actually lives is handled by the previous steps. So to do what you want I'd expect import statements like `import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile`. javac and Netbeans (through the previous steps) will then look through the jar file automatically for that class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jar file in your project's libraries. Read http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for the library as to what the calls are and then call the required methods in order to accomplish what you are doing. Before you do that you will have to import the jar in to your project...